# Why Vue.js can't update the value once it has been set through $refs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, rendering

Why doesn't the title change here once the callback function finishes executing nor when I click on the Change title button?

This is an example from a Udemy VueJS course and it runs fine on the video but I just can't seem to make it work on my side no matter what I try. I hope the question is understandable and well formulated.

```js
var vm1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app1',
  data: {
    title: 'The VueJS Instance',
  },
  methods: {
    updateTitle: function(title) {
      this.title = title;
    }
  }
});

vm1.$refs.heading.innerText = 'Something else';

setTimeout(function() {
  vm1.title = 'Changed by Timer';
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app1">
  <h1 ref="heading">{{ title }}</h1>
  <button v-on:click="updateTitle('a')" ref="myButton">Change title</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

$refs is non-reactive,so you can't do data binding with it.
Check the documentation https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

If you want to use $refs to change value, you have to directly refer to it with property.

```js
var vm1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app1',
  data: {
    title: 'The VueJS Instance',
  },
  methods: {
    updateTitle: function(title) {
      this.$refs.heading.innerText = title;
    }
  }
});

vm1.$refs.heading.innerText = 'Something else';
setTimeout(function() {
  vm1.$refs.heading.innerText = 'Changed by Timer';
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app1">
  <h1 ref="heading">{{ title }}</h1>
  <button v-on:click="updateTitle('a')" ref="myButton">Change title</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, but most likely this is happening because you manually messed with the DOM outside of Vue's knowledge.

Vue does a lot of bookkeeping in order to make patching the DOM as efficient as possible. By setting the `innerText` of the heading element, the existing text node (that Vue controls) is being replaced by a new text node that Vue doesn't control. When Vue re-renders the component, it detects that only the `title` data property changed, so it patches the old text node which no longer exists in the DOM because it got replaced.